# If A and B are independent, can P(C | A, B) be expressed only in terms of P(A), P(B), P(C | A), and P(C | B)?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

Conditional probability question.

Let's say I have...

- three random variables: `A`, `B`, `C`
- `A` and `B` are independent
- `C` depends on `A` and `B`

My question is: can I express `P(C | A, B)` in terms of `P(A)`, `P(B)`, `P(C | A)`, and `P(C | B)`?

Asking this because I'm studying Bayesian networks, and I'm wondering if it's possible to define a node's "complete" conditional probability distribution (i.e. `P(X | all parents of X)`) given only "partially conditional" distributions, like one conditional per parent (`{P(X | parent 1), P(X | parent 2), ...}`).

I have a hunch that this is not possible. I think we also need to know `P(A, B | C)`. Just struggling to prove this analytically.

Answer (score 3):

If you had known $P(A|B,C)$, then you could calculate $P(C|A,B)$ as follows:

$$P(C|A,B)=\frac{P(A|B,C)P(B,C)}{P(A,B)}$$

You already know the joint probabilities $P(A,B)$ and $P(B,C)$ with what you have.

Due to the usage of Bayes Rule, without a three-term (e.g. involving $A,B,C$ together) probability expression, it doesn't make sense to calculate another three-term probability expression.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was wondering, using Bayes rule with  a three term expression, if it would be possible to drop one of the conditions due to some independence, and turn a three term expression into a two term expression that would be useful, given the quantities I knew. Oh well.

Comment: @grisaitis pairwise independences between two variables doesn't mean conditional independence given some other, so you cannot reduce a triple term expression into double term expression. You need to have something like $A$ and $C$ are independent given $B$ to reduce $P(A|B,C)$ to $P(A|B)$ for example.